# How to capture the active window with EmguCV

Tags: c#, opencv

Generally I need capture the active window for the future work with EmguCV (namely with Image class). With a help of some learning videos I got the picture from my webcam:

```
Capture capWebcam = null;
capWebcam = new Capture();
Image<Bgr, Byte> myImage = capWebcam.QueryFrame()
```

Instead of it, I want capture the active window. How can I do it?

Comment: What version of OpenCV are you using? I note that OpenCV is generally not concerned with image acquisition, only image processing (it's why its Webcam-capture library is rather spartan compared to Windows' DirectShow and MediaFoundation APIs). Last time I checked (which was almost 8 years ago) OpenCV didn't have any ability to capture screenshots, so you probably need to use a platform-specific API to do that. I assume you're on Windows?

Comment: Yes, windows 10. So far I use EmguCV 2.4.0.1717